# How do I collect information about my website's visitors?

Tags: php, javascript, statistics

Is there some way to store:

- A visitor's IP Address
- What time a visitor visited my site
- How many times they visited

I know there is a way to do this **without** PHP, just with Javascript and some text files.

How it would I do this in PHP?

Comment: Ask Facebook and/or Cambridge Analytics.

Answer (score 12):

It's a very easy task.

You can do this with the help of php. You can get many types of information about client visiting your site. You can get to know about the ip address, date, time, operating system, browser, isp of that ip address and many more things. You will have to use php and mysql !

firstly create a table in mysql.

**create_table_track.php**

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database name";

$connId = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Cannot connect to server");
$selectDb = mysql_select_db($database,$connId) or die("Cannot connect to database"); 

$result = "CREATE TABLE track(
`id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`tm` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
`ref` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`agent` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
`ip_value` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`domain` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
`host_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
`tracking_page_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 "; 
 
if (mysql_query($result))
{
 print "Success in TABLE creation!......";
} 
else 
{
die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}


?>'
```

This is the first part of getting the information about client.
This file will create a table named "track" in mysql database.
Now to store information in this table, you will have to create another file.

**example.php**

```
<html>
<?php


// fill in your databasa data here!
$server = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database name";

$connId = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Cannot connect to server");
$selectDb = mysql_select_db($database,$connId) or die("Cannot connect to database");


$tracking_page_name="example";
$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host_name = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO track(tm, ref, agent, ip, tracking_page_name, host_name)    VALUES(curdate(),'$ref','$agent','$ip','$tracking_page_name','$host_name')";
$test=mysql_query($strSQL);

?>
</html>
```

Now the above file will extract information from client computer and store it in the database.

Now to show the information stored in database,, we wil use following file---

**show track.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user name","password");
mysql_select_db("database name", $con) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM track";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">id</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">time</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">http referer</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">user agent</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">ip address</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">ip value</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">domain</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">tracking_page_name</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Host_name</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"tm");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"ref");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"agent");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"ip");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"ip_value");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"domain");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"tracking_page_name");
$f9=mysql_result($result,$i,"host_name");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f9; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 10):

There's no way to store anything on a client computer using pure javascript. It runs in a sandboxed environment that doesn't allow you to perform such tasks. You could send an AJAX request to a server side script that will perform the necessary steps to persists the data. Another option of course is to use some service like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/analytics/sign_up.html#utm_source=en_gb-ha-region4-sk_analytics&utm_medium=ha&utm_campaign=en_gb&utm_term=google%20analytics) which will take care of persisting statistics about your site visits by including a simple script at the end of your pages.

Comment: +1 for Google Analytics - it's the gold standard of activity tracking these days.

Comment: -1 for Google Analytics - it's the best spying machine with activity these days.

Answer (score 2):

as he said WITHOUT PHP!! (only textfiles) i would prefer using jsonp with a callback function and a webservice like ip-api.com or ipinfo.io

```
function fire() {
    var url = "http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=func";
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

function func(response) {
    alert(response.hostname); // for example hostname
}

document.onload = fire();
```

instead of response.hostname you can alert everything what the service gives you back like

```
{
  "ip": "178.165.128.3",
  "hostname": "178.165.128.3.wireless.dyn.drei.com",
  "city": null,
  "region": null,
  "country": "AT",
  "loc": "47.3333,13.3333",
  "org": "AS12635 Hutchison Drei Austria GmbH"
}
```

the time you can get by

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
```

and the count how often visitor cames i would store in local storage..

Answer (score 0):

you will need some kind of server side processing if you want to write to files on the server.
if you want client-side storage, it is a relativley new feature (HTML5), but doesn't allow access to the filesystem directly.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, If I understand what you are trying to do, what you are trying to accomplish is very easy.

To get the visitors IP Address, you would simply use the $_SERVER superglobal, like so:

```
<?php $_SERVER['ip_address']; ?>
```

Then, to get the time, you would simply use:

```
<?php time(); ?>
```

Now, the slightly more tricky part, how many times they visited. You need to put the above into a database, e.g. mysql.

Create a database schema, with the following columns: id, ipAddress, time and numOfVisits.
You would need to have some php logic at the start of your webpage to check if the users IP Address is already in the database, and if it is, increment the numOfVisits column. You would obviously need to log the output of time() into the time column also.

In essence, that's how you would do what you are asking in PHP. 
Hope this helped :)