# PHP script not writing data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code from another Stack Overflow question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451073/how-do-i-collect-information-about-my-websites-visitors).

I have a mysql table called track in my database.

```
$server = "host";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "database";

$connId = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Cannot connect to     server");
$selectDb = mysql_select_db($database,$connId) or die("Cannot connect to database");


$tracking_page_name="example";
$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host_name = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO track (tm, ref, agent, ip, tracking_page_name, host_name)         VALUES(curdate(),'$ref','$agent','$ip','$tracking_page_name','$host_name')";
$test=mysql_query($strSQL);
```

Basically I want all the data this script collects to be put into my database. However, no matter what I type, even if I change the variables to text, nothing gets written into the database. I can read from the database just fine using another script, but I can't get this one to add any piece of info to the db. Is there a typo I just can't seem to find?

I just want information about anyone who visits the page this gets included in.

EDIT: I was trying to fill a field called "host_name", but in my database it had a different name. The original script shown here would not show the error and I did not ever run a check to see if all my fields are in order. That was the error.

Comment: mysql deprecated use myslqi preapared statement

Comment: what sould I replace it with?

Comment: try to echo your query. if query give values than problem in connection, so use mysqli if face problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: You selected my answer but I'm curious; could you share what the problem was? It helps us learn as well.

Comment: I know there are some sql injection exploits, but I don't care that much. I'm using this script mostly as a personal project that may never see the light of day. However, just as a thought: couldn't someone who knows I'm logging this info just make a js that refreshes my page non-stop just to fill up my db?

Comment: What is your problem, say I coundn't understand can to explain a liitle bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many possibilities:

1. If the user `user` has read permissions but not write permissions on the database or the table, read ops will succeed but write ops will fail.
2. If this is a MyISAM table, the table may be locked by another process. Read operations would work but write operations would not
3. Maybe the table or a field you're trying to write to does not exist or is misspelled

Change...

```
$test=mysql_query($strSQL);
```

to...

```
if(!$test=mysql_query($strSQL)) die(mysql_error());
```

It will show you why the operation failed ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)).

Also, if you're starting don't use `MySQL` functions. They are being removed from PHP so you're just giving yourself more work to do in the future. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` instead ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)).

Finally, **never** just insert text you got from the browser in an SQL query. The values of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` can be manipulated by your user to be anything, including a string that causes you to execute whatever query the user wants (delete your tables, exfiltrate your data...).  Learn about *prepared statements* and *parameterized queries* and use them instead

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I had no field "host name" there.

Comment: Cool. Please take the other advice to heart. Notice everyone is telling you the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

echo this line:

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO track (tm, ref, agent, ip, tracking_page_name, host_name)         VALUES(curdate(),'$ref','$agent','$ip','$tracking_page_name','$host_name')"
```

and run it on a SQL console. Lookout for errors and make sure the values are being passed in.